# Can i post signup form on users page with facebook graph api - PHP

Tags: php, webforms, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I would like to post subscription webform on users Facebook page's dynamically .
Up until now i did not find any solution.
I know how to post on users wall/page but i cannot make HTML posts as they appear as plain text.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly; Then I'm fairly sure you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML posts are not possible on Facebook, only simple text. And the text always must be 100% user generated, prefilling is not allowed. See the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

That´s just a side note though, because if you post "as Page" on your Page, you are the one who fills in the text anyway.

The only way to use HTML on a Facebook Page is by using a Page App: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs

Comment: Well,the question might not be very specific. I would like to create something like this http://www.jotform.com/help/22-Adding-Form-to-Facebook-Pages , just we have our own web from builder and i need to add option to place the form on selected user fb page

Comment: your question is about html in wall posts, which is not possible. but your comment is about page apps, which is a completely different topic. those are just iframes. i will add a link to my answer.

Comment: well i am confused what actually should i do in order to get start with the coding :( .I am waiting your answer.Thanks.

Comment: well...first, you need to learn html, css and javascript. then maybe a server language. and then open the link about page tabs, it´s a good tutorial.

Comment: again, open the last link in my answer. everything is in there.

Comment: Thanks i did not see that you edited the post.I cannot vote because i do not have enough reputation  :(